# vagrant cannot start VirtualBox VM after moving from 18.04 to 19.04

Tags: virtualbox, 19.04, vagrant

I moved my home folder to a new laptop. before I used Ubuntu 18.04 and on my new Laptop I use Kubuntu 19.04.

I copied all relevant folders to my new system, but vagrant cannot start the old container on the new system:

```
vagrant up trusty64
Bringing machine 'trusty64' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> trusty64: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end
  config.vm.define "trusty64" do |node|
    node.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    node.vm.hostname = "blimus"
    node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.22", netmask: "255.255.255.0", mac: "08002786814f" # set mac for ruben VM 14.04
    node.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", args: "trusty"
  end

  config.vm.box_check_update = false
end
```

It seems like the problem is, that virtualbox service doesn't run:

```
$ service virtualbox status
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-07-30 20:12:55 CEST; 3h 35min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Jul 30 20:12:54 einstein systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jul 30 20:12:54 einstein virtualbox[1209]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Jul 30 20:12:55 einstein virtualbox[1209]:  * modprobe vboxnetflt failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Jul 30 20:12:55 einstein virtualbox[1209]:    ...fail!
Jul 30 20:12:55 einstein systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 30 20:12:55 einstein systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 30 20:12:55 einstein systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.


$ sudo modprobe vboxnetflt
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxnetflt': Operation not permitted

$  dmesg|grep vbox
[   10.008780] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   10.016866] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
[   10.036574] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 1799999896 Hz
[   10.036576] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.0.6_Ubuntu (interface 0x00290008)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `virtualbox-dkms` installation was broken. My fix was:

```
apt purge virtualbox-dkms && apt install virtualbox-dkms
```

choose a password on reistallation and reboot the system. You will be asked to do the MOK again, choose to do so and choose the first key, enter your passwor and reboot.

now:

```
$ dmesg |grep vboxdrv
vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 1799998716 Hz
vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.0.6_Ubuntu (interface 0x00290008)
vboxdrv: 0000000000000000 VMMR0.r0
boxdrv: 0000000000000000 VBoxDDR0.r0

$ dmesg|grep 'UEFI:MokListRT '|grep -i ubuntu
Loaded UEFI:MokListRT cert 'kubuntu Secure Boot Module Signature key: ..............' linked to secondary sys keyring

$ service virtualbox status
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: active
```